# How to get the authentication access token after Authenticate Users with an Identity Provider?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-api, google-oauth

I am working in a xmarine android c# project. where I want to access google contact from my c# android app. For This I have used the below mentioned link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth
I am unable to get access_token in OnAuthCompleted method. How can I do so?

I am giving my code below for better understanding.

```
public void googleAuthentication()
        {
            var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                                Configuration.ClientID,
                                string.Empty,
                                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
                                new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"),
                                new Uri(Configuration.RedirectUrl),
                                new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"),
                                isUsingNativeUI: true);

            authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
            authenticator.Error += Authenticator_Error;

            var a = authenticator.GetUI(this);
            StartActivity(a);            
        }
```

also I have added another activity in my project for custom URL scheme as per the above link. but it is not working, code is as follows:

```
[Activity(Label = "CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "com.googleusercontent.apps.94221532031-00o4meh3gmmq4g8r3ersa6m3oskmbkat" },
        DataPath = "/oauth2redirect")]
    public class CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity : Activity
    {
        public static OAuth2Authenticator Auth;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your application here
            var uri = new Uri(Intent.Data.ToString());
            // Load redirectUrl page            
            CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity.Auth.OnPageLoading(uri);
            Finish();
        }
    }
```

please help me how to get access_token in *async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)* method

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure you have enable the settings correctly

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#setup

Please note:The credentials settings, If you want to running your application in Android, you should set the Application type to Android. If you edit the Oauth ID in google console, you can got the resule like following screenshot.

[image]

You said the `CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity` not work, Is this activity did not appear? If so, you can add a Layout and  delete the `Finish()` and make a test.

```
    [Activity(Label = "CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true, 
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "com.googleusercontent.apps.991626672383-b159bdtjq2pt29r7hrm90qi7l3qet99j" },
    DataPath = "/oauth2redirect")]
public class CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        // Convert Android.Net.Url to Uri
        var uri = new Uri(Intent.Data.ToString());

        // Load redirectUrl page
        AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri);

        //Finish();
    }
}
```

Here is my demo running GIF.

[image]

I upload my demo to github, you can refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/OAuthDemo

Comment: Hello @Leon Lu - MSFT I tried with your code and got the below result, requesting you to check in answer section for better understanding.

Comment: Did you refer to this thrad?https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/  Did you want to get the login user's email?

Comment: Yes Sir, I followed the same link, https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/ but some how my project is not working , not getting why. https://github.com/SoumenHalder88/soumenXamProject.git

Comment: I notice this thread:https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/, it got the access_token for login users' email address, if you want to get it. you can use request account ` var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();` Then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to Deserialize it.